# Como dar update em um botão dentro de um <ui:repeat>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-3.5

Vamos ao meu problema. Eu tenho dois <p:commandLink> dentro de um <ui:repeat>. Esses botões simulam checkbox. Então gostaria de ao clicar neles dar update na linha específica dentro do <ui:repeat> atualizando assim o botão a ser renderizado.
Dando update em um  <p:outputPanel> que está acima na árvore de elementos ele funciona. O problema é que para uma lista com muitos registros esse update faz com que se volte ao topo da lista, o que para muitos registros acaba sendo dificultoso quando se precisa adicionar varios itens que estão abaixo na lista.

```
<tbody>
   <ui:repeat value="#{myBean.itens}" var="item" varStatus="index">
      <tr class="myCustomClass" id="item#{item.id}">
         <th>
            <p:commandLink
               rendered="#{myConditionRendered}"
               actionListener="#{myBean.deselect(item)}"
               update=":panelGroupArroundId"
               process="@this">
               <i style="font-size: 15px;" class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
            </p:commandLink>
            <p:commandLink
               rendered="#{!myConditionRendered}"
               actionListener="#{myBean.select(item)}"
               update=":panelGroupArroundId"
               process="@this">
               <i style="font-size: 15px;"
                  class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
            </p:commandLink>
         </th>
         <td>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.field1}"/>
         </td>
         ...                                                         
      </tr>
   </ui:repeat>
</tbody>
```

JSF versão 2.1, Primefaces versão 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colocando um form e um panelGroup ao redor dos botoes resolve o problema.

```
<tbody>
   <ui:repeat value="#{myBean.itens}" var="item" varStatus="index">
      <tr class="myCustomClass" id="item#{item.id}">
         <th>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGroup id="idGroup">
                    <p:commandLink
                     rendered="#{myConditionRendered}"
                     actionListener="#{myBean.deselect(item)}"
                     update="idGroup"
                     process="@this">
                    <i style="font-size: 15px;" class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                    </p:commandLink>
                    <p:commandLink
                     rendered="#{!myConditionRendered}"
                     actionListener="#{myBean.select(item)}"
                     update="idGroup"
                     process="@this">
                    <i style="font-size: 15px;"
                     class="fa fa-square-o"></i>
                   </p:commandLink>

                </h:panelGroup>       
            </h:form>
         </th>
         <td>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.field1}"/>
         </td>
         ...                                                         
      </tr>
   </ui:repeat>
</tbody>
```